# Not Removing the previous Highlighted (selected) Text while searching the text from page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am doing the search functionality of text .I am facing one problem actually first time i search it is working fine .But when i search again and press search it is showing the previous first search highlighted text.Not showing the search text.How to solve that issue.
Here is my code.
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/z7fjW/143/

```
function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm, selector) {
    if(searchTerm) {
        //var wholeWordOnly = new RegExp("\\g"+searchTerm+"\\g","ig"); //matches whole word only
        //var anyCharacter = new RegExp("\\g["+searchTerm+"]\\g","ig"); //matches any word with any of search chars characters
        var selector = selector || "#bodyContainer";                             //use body as selector if none provided
        var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm,"ig");
        var matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
        if(matches) {
$('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');     //Remove old search highlights
                $(selector).html($(selector).html().replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='match'>"+searchTerm+"</span>"));
           $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');
            $('#next').on('click',i=1, function()
        {   alert(i); 
            $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');                                                                   $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');

          i=i+1; 
        k=i-2;
         alert(i);
     }); 
                  $('#previous').on('click',k=1, function()
        {   alert(k);
            $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');                                                                   $('.match').eq(k).addClass('highlighted');         
          k=k-1;
            i=k+2;
     });




            if($('.highlighted:first').length) {             //if match found, scroll to where the first one appears
                $(window).scrollTop($('.highlighted:first').position().top);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-button').on("click",function() {
        if(!searchAndHighlight($('#search-term').val())) {
            alert("No results found");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove all those classes you setted while searching, for the highlighted text, before running again the search, otherwise those classes will remain:

```
$(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted").removeClass("match");
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7fjW/144/

hope it helps

Comment: But now it now scrolling down ..Example search "naveen"

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your replace code, because when you lose the scrolling functionality, the outputted HTML is like this: <p class="<span class='match'>em</span>ptyBlock1000" >